# Spring Cloud Data Flow Remote RabbitMQ Server Config

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-data, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to SCDF and am trying to get started with a RabbitMQ transport layer and SCDF version 1.2.2. I have setup RabbitMQ in a separate VM and have the SCDF local server and SCDF shell jar in one VM. Can someone suggest how I can specify the server details of my RabbitMQ (which is in a different host in the same network) for SCDF to use as a transport.

For reasons outside my control I need to use the MQ setup in a different machine. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

SCDF doesn't require RabbitMQ and I think you are trying to use RabbitMQ as the binder for your Spring Cloud Stream applications that are orchestrated via SCDF.

You would need to configure the properties mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#rabbit-binder-properties)

You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_properties) on how to specify these properties at SCDF.

Comment: I am new to SCDF. From what I understand to communicate messages between any source and sink SCDF requires a MQ. It may be either Kafka or RabbitMQ. Am i correct? 

I can see that installing Kafka is a requirement for installing SCDF.

Comment: Yes, That is correct. What I meant was, your messaging layer is only used by the application you deploy via SCDF and not directly by the SCDF itself. For the source and sink applications,  these messaging middlewares need to be configured with the above mentioned properties via binder configurations.

Comment: Hi, your link was quite helpful, but I am still unable to create the exact apps. I am deploying the app for scdf stream create --name foostream --definition "time | log" like this after importing for rabbit mq binder. can you tell me how i can set properties like spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.nodes that are mentioned in the doc

Comment: A little breakdown help would be helpful :)

Comment: You can use this as a sample: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#passing_producer_consumer_properties

Comment: 2017-09-19 00:54:58.322  WARN 12293 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=foostream.time, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing... org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Getting Rabbit Admin exception

Comment: 2017-09-19 00:55:03.329  WARN 12293 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Failed to declare queue: Queue [name=foostream.time.foostream, durable=true, autoDelete=false, exclusive=false, arguments={}], continuing... org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: This looks like you have something misconfigured (the connection parameters) or the time out is too short to establish the connection. Have you tried this by running RabbitMQ and SCDF running locally?